# Beautified URLs uglified by Google

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo

I have a little problem that's been bothering me for the last few months.

First the good news: with the help of the massive SO community I was able to rewrite my ugly URLs into nice ones, e.g. `website.com/page.ast?ln=nl` into `website.com/nl/page`. For that little `.htaccess` Apache magic I'm eternally thankful to the SO community.

But happily developing along, I came across a nasty truth in Google search results...

Google shows the ugly URLs in their search:

`website.com/nl/selfdesign.ast?ln=fa`

[image]

While:

1. My website has nice hyperlinks in its menu system:

   `<a href="selfdesign">designing your own website</a>`
2. When on the page, that website loads and Firefox's URL bar shows the nice URL:

   `http://website.com/nl/selfdesign`
3. My site page's code reveals the canonical following meta:

So, I think my beautified URLs have been uglified by Google. Thanks very much!
How is it possible for Google to show the ugly URLs after all these months I spent beautifying my links?

#### Update 2

So how can I redirect URLs like `website.com/nl/webpage.ext?ln=yy` to `website.com/nl/webpage`, essentially removing the unnecessary part which doesn't do anything?

`.xxx?ln=yy` where `xxx` is is a 2 or 3 letter char (extension) and `yy` is a language (can be `nl`, `be`, `fr` but also `zh-cn`, etc.)  .

Again anything past and including the `.extension?ln=whatever` can be completely removed and redirected towards.

Comment: You need to setup a 301 redirect from the original URL to the friendly URL. If you can share your redirect rules (.htaccess), I can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also setup 301 redirects for all your legacy URLs to your new scheme. This 301 redirect will tell Google to update its URLs in the search engine.

### Update 2

Here is how you would reverse it:

```
RewriteRule   /nl/webpage(.*)      /nl/webpage [R=301]
```

Comment: Make regex statements for your old URLs and redirect to new ones.

Comment: Ive updated my question, under Update 2, does this info help? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the update Nick. If I understand correctly, 1. I will make one rewrite rule per file/webpage that I ahve and 2. whatever the extension(s) or ?ln=.... etc will all be catched/caught and redirected to the beautifull url?